# How do I include a Julia file in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: windows, julia

I was able to create a Jupyter notebook for Julia. I then proceeded to create a new folder, and then upload a source file to it.

How can I include this file (as in "include("the_file.jl")).

I am using Windows 10.

TIA.
Henry

Answer (score 3):

Precisely as you would do it in the REPL or anywhere else.

```
include("the_file.jl")
```

If this doesn't work for you than you are probably in the wrong folder, which you can check with `pwd()` and change with `cd(path::String)`.

Alternatively, you can specify the full path rather than the relative path:

```
include("/full/path/to/the_file.jl")
```

If you created the folder from within Julia, than you probably want

```
include("myfolder/the_file.jl")
```